# Set Visibility true or false for 2 elements using dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have usercontrol like this :

it is header user control, i am using this control to few pages,

```
 <Grid>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource PuzzleTalkHeader}"  Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.GlobalApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Image x:Name="imgCoin" Grid.Column="3" Height="24" Width="24" Source="/Assets/Images/Coin.png" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbxEarnPoints" Grid.Column="5" Text="15000"/>
        </Grid>
```

i want to set the one property like this : `isVisibleEarnPoints="True"`

```
<UserControls:Header Grid.Row="0" isVisibleEarnPoints="True"/>
```

if `isVisibleEarnPoints="True"` then i want the `imgCoin` and `tbxEarnPoints` should be visiable and if it is false, then those element hide

i am trying something like this, but i am not able get result, can you help me?

```
    public partial class Header : UserControl
    {
        public Header()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        //public bool isVisiableEarnPoints
        //{
        //  set
        //  {
        //      if(value)
        //      {
        //          imgCoin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        //          tbxEarnPoints.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        //      }
        //      else
        //      {
        //          imgCoin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        //          tbxEarnPoints.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        //      }
        //  }
        //}

        public int isVisiableEarnPoints { get; set; }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("isVisiableEarnPoints", typeof(isVisiableEarnPoints), typeof(Header), new PropertyMetadata(YourDPCallBack));

        private static void YourDPCallBack(DependencyObject instance, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            Header control = (Header)instance;

        }
    }
}
```

Updated Question as per comments :

[1] :

```
public partial class Header : UserControl
    {
        public Header()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private bool _isisVisiableEarnPoints;
        public bool isVisiableEarnPoints
        {
            get{

                return _isisVisiableEarnPoints;
            }
            set
            {
                _isisVisiableEarnPoints=value;
            }
        }
    }
```

and then bind this property like this :

```
<Image x:Name="imgCoin" Grid.Column="3" Height="24" Width="24" Source="/Assets/Images/Coin.png" Visibility="{Binding isVisiableEarnPoints, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"  />
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbxEarnPoints" Grid.Column="5" Text="15000" Visibility="{Binding isVisiableEarnPoints, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
```

and used in usercontrol like this :

```
<UserControls:Header Grid.Row="0" isVisiableEarnPoints="False"/>
```

but still it is not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purpose int `XAML` of the controls that you are going to hide/show bind a that `bool` property you change *and* assign also [Converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) to every one of them, in order to convert boolean value receeved into appropriate [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the control.

here is actually concrete example of implementing custom converter:

[Using a value converter to bind to Visibility in the Silverlight data grid](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/07/visibility-type-converter/) 
(it's a `Silverlight`, but the concept is the same)

Or simply may use [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) provided by framework if its behavior satisfies your requirements.

Comment: do you want me to write  Visibility="{Binding true/false, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" ??

Comment: sir, i want to create new property like this : <UserControls:Header Grid.Row="0" isVisibleEarnPoints="True"/>

Comment: So bind that property to the ViewModel's boolean property, and assign Converter accordingly

Comment: OK, i set like this :Image x:Name="imgCoin" Grid.Column="3" Height="24" Width="24" Source="/Assets/Images/Coin.png" Visibility="{Binding isVisiableEarnPoints, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"  />
  <TextBlock x:Name="tbxEarnPoints" Grid.Column="5" Text="15000" Visibility="{Binding isVisiableEarnPoints, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />

Comment: <UserControls:Header Grid.Row="0" isVisiableEarnPoints="False"/>

Comment: `isVisiableEarnPoints` has to be a part of you `ViewModel`, and assign accordingly from the code behind. It is possible to do also in `XAML`, I guess, but it's kind of messy. The code you wrote may not wotk, as at momment UserControl get `false` the binding to others may not be initialized yet, so no event will be fired to update UI. ry to set that property from the code behind, once the binding seted upp..

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.. But why you want to create dependency property ,, you can directly attach the viewmodel property to visibilty of controls you have.

But if you want to create a new property like IsVisibleEarnPoints then you have to create DP.

For Eg.`

```
 public partial class YOUCLASS: UserControl
    {
        public YOUCLASS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }
 public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVisibleEarnPointsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsVisibleEarnPoints", typeof(bool), typeof(YOURCLASS), new UIPropertyMetadata((bool)false, OnStateChange));

        public bool IsVisibleEarnPoints
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)GetValue(IsVisibleEarnPointsProperty );
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(IsVisibleEarnPointsProperty , value);
            }
        }

        private static void OnStateChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue is bool)
            {
                var source = (YOURCLASS)d;
                source.SetState((bool)e.NewValue);
            }
        }

        public void SetState(bool isDisabled)
        {   

if(isDisabled)
{
imgecoin.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
//same for other control
}
else
{
// Do whatever you want.
}




    }`
```